# Admob Reward Video Ads isn't showing Real Video Ads

Tags: android, video, admob, ads

I am trying to implement AdMob Reward Video Ads. As I am Implementing the test/sample ads, the video ad is showing perfectly and in time, but When I implement the real ads(ad unit ID), It is not showing the Real Video Ads. Where the Interstitial Ads are showing Perfectly and in time. I am adding the code guys-

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ad unit ID");
    prepareAd();
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
public void  prepareAd() {
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ad unit ID");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    isVisible = true;
    if (scheduler == null) {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("hello", "world");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded() && isVisible) {
                            mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", " Interstitial not loaded");
                            displayInterstitial();
                        }


                        prepareAd();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 42, 42, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}
private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ad unit ID",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

The logcat is here too-

```
    01-28 17:41:32.357 7200-30384/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam I/hello: world
    01-28 17:41:32.357 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam D/TAG:  Interstitial not loaded
    01-28 17:41:32.384 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
    01-28 17:41:32.413 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam I/Ads: Starting ad request.
    01-28 17:41:32.414 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("8D2245D8347B7CF7C7C2C4B37E12F275") to get test ads on this device.
    01-28 17:41:33.225 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:30] Constructor
    01-28 17:41:33.229 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
    01-28 17:41:33.230 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
    01-28 17:41:33.270 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
    01-28 17:41:33.305 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 7200
    01-28 17:41:33.305 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
    01-28 17:41:33.653 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
    01-28 17:41:34.938 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
    01-28 17:41:34.938 7200-7200/com.deb.srikishnerastottorosotonam I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
```

Here is my Layout Page:-

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Button2"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="Banner Ad ID">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using same ID for intialization and for `mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId`?

Comment: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad. - problem with your layout.. update your question with your layout... search on stackoverflow with above error

Comment: hi @yupi, I am using The separate IDs for initialization, banner, Interstitial & Video Ads given by Admob.

Comment: I have launched more than 3 apps in Play store. The very first app I launched was showing Video ads Perfectly on my real Device, but then every app I developed was not showing only the Video Ads. Interstitial Ads Showing perfectly.